# Detect list of homogeneous elements in a webpage

Tags: html, parsing, dom, web-crawler

I need to detect a sequence of consecutive identical elements in the DOM of a page. These elements could be div's or li's or span's and could contain other elements. The elements have in common the fact that they appear consecutively and have the same inner structure.

The problem i am trying to solve is automatically parsing search results. The solution i am trying to find would produce a list of all lists of such elements (for example a page might contain a list with the search results and other irrelevant lists of elements); this solution would have to be generic enough that i do not need to know the structure of the page beforehand.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give an example of the structure you're trying to identify. It may change the solution. For example if the structure of the piece you are looking for highly known then a regular expression can be used if components can be nested in different ways then a regular expression could get you into trouble.

Comment: An example list of results would be:

  <li>
  <a href="">
    <span>Result 1</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="">
    <span>Result 2</span></a>
  </li>
  ...
  <li>
  <a href="">
    <span>Result n</span></a>
  </li>
 
 Any file can contain multiple such lists

Comment: And you want to match on all instances of this?

<li><a><span></span></a></li>

Comment: I want to match any consecutive structures that are identical. This is just an example. A structure that appears in such a list could also be something like <div><a><span></span></a></div>. The structure of the elements of a list is not predetermined. This is what makes this problem somewhat difficult for me. One such approach, as answered my mpasko256 would be to load the dom and parse it as a tree looking and look for identical subtrees that are children of the same parent. I'm wondering, however, if i can't find a simpler approach.

Comment: If you don't have a rigid structure then you will need to load a DOM as mmpasko256 indicated. What's your chosen language?

Comment: For this project, Python 3.

Comment: If my answer was an adequate solution can you please mark it as the accepted solution. Otherwise you may want to answer your own question, so that others can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption:** you're building a configurable html web crawler using python that is intended for data mining

**Steps to retrieve data:**

- Downloaded the html page
- build a query capable DOM; try: http://thehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
- query for the appropriate data according to the web crawler configuration

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in general is too complex to apply some kind of regular expressions. It probably implies context grammar.

You have to implement an algoritm by yourself to solve this. The simplest one that I keep in mind is:

1. Follow DOM tree recursively
2. In any recursion step:

   1. Remember  first subelement in a node.
   2. Go to the next subelement and compare with the one kept in memory.
   3. Remember last visited subelement.
   4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you finish processing all subelements in a node

Comment: Thanks, i'll go with this approach if i can't find a simpler solution. Writing my own parser was what i was trying to avoid :)

Comment: This is a less than ideal solution for someone who is building a web crawler. If he is using javascript then this is great, but if he is not then it is a less than ideal solution. If his match requirements are as simple as it seems loading the page into a dom structure is a waste of resources.